# How can I implement computational step time in simulink?

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink

I have to implement the following blocks in simulink:

[image: block diagram]

But I am not sure how I can implement these exp functions. Do I have to implement them as laplace transform format?

I know that `e^(-at) = 1/(s+a)`.

But what will be the function for `e^(-sTc)`?

Comment: If Tc > 0, then this the laplace transform of dirac delta function in the time domain (t-Tc)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the variable time delay block.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).